# get unique words in text stream

Tags: algorithm, space-complexity

At a given instance can we find out unique words in a text stream.
One naive solution i can think of is using a hashmap to keep words count.

But this would require keeping words which have word count more than 1 in hashmap. In case of long text stream, it will be lot of words to maintain. Is there a way to crunch on space complexity for this.

Comment: Why not remove those words from Hashmaps once the count becomes greater than 1 ?

Comment: This will not work if any word occur odd number of times. For example if a word occur 3 times, for first we will add it to Hashmap, for second we will remove it. For third occurrence we will not know whether the word has occurred before and was removed or is it first occurrence of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get the number of distinct words **exactly** without paying the space complexity. However, you can get a reasonably good estimate by using the [Flajolet-Martin](http://ravi-bhide.blogspot.com/2011/04/flajolet-martin-algorithm.html) approach, described on slide 20 of this [slide deck](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs246/slides/16-streams.pdf).

Assuming the data stream consists of a universe of elements chosen from a set of size `N`, you can do the following steps, copied from the slides linked above.

1. Pick a hash function `h` that maps each of the `N` elements to at least `log_2 (N)` bits.
2. For each stream element `a`, let `r(a)` be the number of trailing `0`'s in `h(a)`.
3. Record R = the maximum `r(a)` seen.
4. Estimated number of distinct elements = `2^R`.

Comment: Thanx. Thats what i was thinking, but coming up with such a hash function is the challenge. With few error percentage i.e. collision allowed we can achieve this.